# Fetching and setting the csrf token correctly

Tags: vue.js, flask, post, axios, csrf-token

I'm trying to create a simple application that uses `flask_cors` and `flask_wtf`. However, when I use `flask_wtf` I get a response saying **The CSRF token is missing** when I try to send a POST request.

Here is my back-end application (running on port 3080):

**__init__.py**

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect

cors = CORS()
csrf = CSRFProtect()

def create_app(config):

    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)

    app.config['TESTING'] = True 
    app.config['DEBUG'] = True
    app.config['JSON_SORT_KEYS'] = False
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'You will never guess me!'
    app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY']= True
    app.config['REMEMBER_COOKIE_HTTPONLY'] = True
    app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE'] = 'Strict'
    
    cors.init_app(app)
    csrf.init_app(app)

    with app.app_context():

        from app.views.sanity_bp import sanity_bp

        app.register_blueprint(sanity_bp, url_prefix='/api/sanity')

        return app
```

**sanity_bp.py**

```py
from flask import Blueprint, jsonify, request
from flask_cors import cross_origin
from flask_wtf.csrf import generate_csrf

sanity_bp = Blueprint('sanity_bp', __name__)

@sanity_bp.route('/get/csrf', methods=['GET'])
def get_csrf():
    return jsonify({'csrf_token': generate_csrf()}), 200

@sanity_bp.route('/post', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def post():
    return jsonify('sanity: post request'), 200
```

where I use the `get_csrf()` method to obtain the CSRF token.

The front end (running on port 8080) is given as follows:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    Hello stack <b>overflow</b>!
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

const API = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:3080/api',
});

const csrf = () => {
  API
    .get('/sanity/get/csrf', { credentials: 'same-origin' })
    .then((res) => {
      API.defaults.headers.post['x-csrf-token'] = res.data.csrf_token;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('err = ', err);
    });
};

export default {
  name: 'app',
  methods: {
    sanity() {
      API
        .post('/sanity/post', { message: 'ping' })
        .then((res) => {
          console.log('res.data = ', res.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error('error = ', error);
        });
    },
  },
  created() {
    csrf();
    this.sanity();
  },
};
</script>
```

So when the `created()` method is called, I fetch the CSRF token from the backend and set it as the `x-csrf-token` value in the headers of the `API` function.

However, when I use the POST request in the `sanity()` method, I get a 400 error saying the CSRF token is not set. Furthermore, the `x-csrf-token` key isn't visible in the request header. Why not and where am I going wrong with fetching the token, please?

Comment: Hello, have you been able to resolve this issue? Also, are you running your client and server on different domains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `csrf` function in frontend is asynchronous, you need to wait until it finished before making `this.sanity();` in the `created` function. You can use `async/await`

```
...
async created() {
  await csrf();
  await this.sanity();
},
...
```

Comment: Awesome thanks for the advice ... I'm successfully passing the `X-CSRF-Token` now but getting a `The CSRF session token is missing` error response. I think this is because the session is empty (?) as the `validate_csrf` method in `flask_wtf/csrf.py`, i.e. `session =  <SecureCookieSession {}>`.

Comment: not familiar with `flask-wtf` much, but from [documentation](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/csrf.html#javascript-requests) I see that they use `X-CSRFToken` header. Are you sure that `X-CSRF-Token` is right header?

Comment: Yeah, I changed it to `X-CSRFToken` but get the same error. I'm pretty sure it's the session stuff so I'll look into that.